# Vector length mismatch in Swiss Language Map

Tags: r, dictionary, geomap

I am studying [this website](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/10/geographic-maps-in-r.html)

and don't understand [some things](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/10/geographic-maps-in-r.html):

```
con <- url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/CHE_adm1.RData")
print(load(con))
```

Output is

```
[1] "gadm"
```

The code continues by closing the connection

```
close(con)
```

Then I execute

```
language <- c("german", "german", "german","german",
 "german","german","french", "french",
 "german","german","french", "french", 
 "german", "french","german","german",
 "german","german","german", "german",
 "german","italian","german","french",
 "french","german","german")
```

Honestly, I don't know how the person came up with this matrix, but then I get error

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 27 rows, data has 26
```

Please guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that one "french" entry should be removed from the list at the end of the third line. I don't know if this was a mistake in the example or a change in the data of the map (formerly at http://gadm.org/data/rda/CHE_adm1.RData , now at http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/CHE_adm1.RData). 
In any case I could reproduce the map shown on the website by using:

```
language <- c("german", "german", "german","german",
          "german","german","french", "french",
          "german","german","french",  
          "german", "french","german","german",
          "german","german","german", "german",
          "german","italian","german","french",
          "french","german","german")
```

[image]

Comment: To get the boundaries, you can do `library(raster); g <- getData('GADM', level=1, country='CHE')`

Comment: @RobertH When I attempt this I get `Error in substr(path, nchar(path), nchar(path)) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`

Comment: @RobertH I upgrade to R 3.2.1, and now it processes. Trying to determine how to display the value of `g`, to determine the boundaries

Comment: @Sohni Mahiwal  to display g, type `g`  for metadata and  `plot(g)` to see the boundaries

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the comments section in the link you provided, the author mentioned that he hard-coded the *language* vector. 
http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/10/geographic-maps-in-r.html

Regarding the error, it is pretty straight forward. It notifies that *language* vector has 27 entries while there are only 26 swiss language regions(this might be from **gadm** package AFAIK). So, try deleting one entry from the *language* vector.

Answer (score 1):

RHertel solved the problem, but here is how I would approach it, perhaps useful as a background;

```
library(raster)
g <- getData('GADM', level=1, country='CHE')

# create a data.frame of cantons and language
# set them to German (a common one)
lang <- data.frame(g$NAME_1, lang='German')
lang

# now fix the entries that need to be French or Italian
# and merge back to g (a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame) 
g <- merge(g, lang, by='NAME_1')

spplot(g, 'lang')
```